# Php logging for search input

Tags: php

I have problem with my search log. It does not write to `log.txt` file.

This is my script:

```
class Log{
    public static $logFile     = 'log/log';
    public static $filePointer = null;

    function writeLog($search,$ip,$action){
        if (!(self::$filePointer))
            self::openFile(); 

        $string      = 'Download '.$search.' \n';
        $writetofile = fwrite(self::$filePointer,$string);
    }
    public static function openFile(){
        self::$filePointer = fopen(self::$logFile.'.txt', 'a') 
        or exit ('Can not open self::$logFile!');   
    }   
}

$apa   = "";
$siapa = $_GET['search'];
$act   = $_GET['button'];

switch($act){
    case 'search now': $apa = 'apa';
    break;
}

if($apa){
    $tulis  = Log::writeLog($siapa,$apa);
}
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<form method="get" action="index.php">
<input type="text" name="search" />
<input type="submit" value="Search now" name="button" />
</form>
```

Comment: writeLog() method requires 3 parameters, you are only supplying 2.

Comment: @Cthulhu No, that's actually fine, because `or`, unlike `||`, has a lower precedence than `=`.

Comment: So have you tried to debug this? Can you write to any file at all?

Comment: @Boann Strange, I believed this was impossible for php…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your writelog function expects 3 parameters but you are passing two, and also writelog function is not static.